Is it even possible to build a beacon to announce we exist?
I would like to invent an INTERSTELLAR BEACON which can broadcast a signal that another civilization can detect.
I define a beacon as:

Must be omnidirectional.
Must be noticeable from the next spiral arm (20K ly).
Must actively attract attention.
Must broadcast uncrewed for a million years.

In order to realize such a beacon you can assume having "godlike" powers. Meaning you could even create or move or otherwise influence stars or black holes etc.
Question:
How would/could such a beacon be realized?
If the four criteria cannot be matched, please specify which of them is violated to assess probability of realization and quality of answers.
Background:
I would like to assess if the Fermi paradox holds because I'm not sure if it is not possible to create such a beacon.
I want to use this in a science fiction story as an excuse for why we appear to be alone in the universe.
EDIT: NEAR God like powers. No Violating physics or making galaxy size smiley faces

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This question is similar to: Is it viable to broadcast a signal and be detected within starsystem distance?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You already wrote that the builder of the beacon can have godlike technology. What level of technology is the receiver supposed to have in order to get the message? AlexP's very nice answer assumes roughly current day technology. The ancient Greeks also looked at the stars, should they get the message? Is it sufficient if a civilization 1000 years more advanced then today can see and decode the message?

Easy. Pepper the surface of the Sun liberally with technetium, until its spectral rays display in the light radiated by the star. Tc is a chemical species (arguably the only one in the whole Mendeleiev table) which obtains only by manufacturing: Its presence is an honest signal that technology is being developed and used in the vicinity of the star.

Pulsars with synchronised Frequencies
Since we need something that is stable over a million years essentially all complex artificial constructions are right out. We need planet scale and upwards to even guarantee that whatever we build is still there in a million years.
So my suggestion is this: set up a constellation of pulsars with synchronised frequencies.
A pulsar is a highly magnetised, rotating neutron star that emits beams of electromagnetic radiation from its poles. These beams are observed as pulses of light or radio waves as the star spins, similar to the way a lighthouse works.
Now set up the pulsars in a way such that their frequencies differ, but match up at varying intervals. In essence you are creating a kind of harmonic resonance, creating patterns where the peaks align at certain intervals, producing a regular rhythm or periodic alignment.

Depending on how complex you make this setup it you can make it
impossibly improbable for it to occur naturally (since the pulsars are all independent from each other).
Thus, any observer
must come to the conclusion that it was created by some form of
intelligence.

Now just add enough such setups to make sure that your pulsar formation has a 360 degree sphere cover (since single pulsars only emit in the plain of their rotation).

Best answer. Remember, we're not actually trying to transmit information except for the fact that we exist. The pulsars wouldn't have to be complex, they would just have to be improbable. That just means all the same frequency all in the same place. And if they were all identical the rotation rate would decrease to the same values at the same times. The problem I see is maintaining the orientation for millions of years. But I guess gyroscopic stability would do that. Right?

You could solve the orientation (sky coverage) problem by releasing 1,000 of them in random orientations.

I don't know about slowdown - but apparently some pulsars frequencies are really exceptionally accurate and regular. More accurate than the frequencies of the atomic clocks they are compared against...
https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-pulsars-are-the-most-accurate-clocks-in-the-universe-even-more-accurate-than-atomic-clocks#:~:text=Generally%2C%20the%20regularity%20of%20pulsar,×10%5E−17%20s.

Yes, they're very very accurate. They slow down with time because the rotation causes stuff to be ejected and that energy is lost.

Problem: observers will see this and invent ideas of physics to explain why this is happening. When we first discovered pulsars, we thought they must be an alien signal. What if all pulsars ARE really an alien communication network, almost impossible to form naturally, and we have skewed our understanding of physics to explain them naturally?

@DWKraus Mind blown! :D You just explained why this is actually a brilliant idea.

The classical reference to such a beacon is Jack McDevitt's The Hercules Text (1986).
The basic idea is that one day it comes to pass that radioastronomers who were radioastronoming peacefully with their radiotelescopes notice that a well-known pulsar, one and a half million light-years away, begins to skip beats. The first gap was one beat long, the second gap was two beats, the third was four beats, then eight, then sixteen. And so on. Powers of two. And repeats this sequence for days and days. And then, the pulsar stops beeping completely. And then, when the radioastronomers were at the height of anxiety, it begins transmitting an encyclopedia. Then the action of the novel starts.
The point is that we don't know how the distant and most likely long gone aliens engineered a pulsar to transmit Morse code. (Not really Morse code, but anyway a code sufficiently transparent to enable analysis and eventually translation.) Of course we don't know how they did it. The transmission was engineered by a fantastically advanced civilization, and we are definitely not such a civilization. Maybe eventually the message will reach the point where they tell us how they did it; but the novel does not reach that point, being more concerned with the effects of the really elementary knowledge transmitted in the introductory part. You know, how to make nuclear fusion practical and other such high-school level general knowledge. We don't know how often the pulsar was set to transmit the message; maybe once every hundred years, maybe one every millennium; we cannot know, because this was the first transmission we received, and have had decent radiotelescopes for much less than a century. We don't know for how long the pulsar will keep transmitting the message.
We don't know because our civilization is much too young and much too ignorant.
In general, it is highly unlikely anybody would be able to predict what wondrous feats of engineering humanity will be capable of one thousand years from now, let alone ten thousand years from now.
Let's do a thought experiment. Two of the greatest philosophers and scientists of the 11th century, one thousand years ago, were Abulcasis (Abū al-Qāsim Khalaf ibn al-'Abbās al-Zahrāwī al-Ansari, usually called al-Zahrawi when he is not called Abulcasis) and Avicenna (Abū ʿAlī al-Ḥusayn bin ʿAbdullāh ibn al-Ḥasan bin ʿAlī bin Sīnā al-Balkhi al-Bukhari, usually called Ibn Sina in those rare cases when he is not called Avicenna). Suppose those two great luminaries of the 11th century were asked the question how could one design and manufacture billions of cheap handheld devices which would enable their owners to talk to anybody in the world wherever they might be, to have instant access to all the books and music in the world, and to see lifelike pictures of any object in the world, no matter how distant. Abulcasis and Avicenna would have only answer: that's magic, and magic does not really exist except in fairy tales.
And this is the case with us 21st century people and the interstellar beacon. Today we cannot design it, and we cannot even imagine how it could be designed. But in one thousand years from now, maybe we shall be able to engineer a pulsar to broadcast Wikipedia over the vast expanses of interstellar space. And if not within one thousand years from now, then surely within the next ten thousand years.

Wow, modulated pulsar! That's a great idea! The only problem is, it's not omnidirectional. It only signals a tight beam from the north and south poles. The beam is 2 cones extending outward at an angle equal to the angle between the magnetic and the rotational axes.  Also, I wouldn't use powers of two, I'd broadcast prime numbers like David Bowman did in Jupiter orbit in Space Odyssey. In the novel. Clark said he did that because there's no natural process that generates prime numbers.

@MissUnderstands: (1) I have rejected your edit, because I learned English decades ago and the word humankind is not part of my active English vocabulary. I understand what it means, it is just too new for me. Maybe we can compromise and use the word "humanity"? (2) The beams are not particularly tight. This is a misconception. They are typically quite a few degrees wide, but can be tens of degrees wide, depending on the particular pulsar. If you arrange to use pulsars with 29° wide beams you only need 50 of them to cover the 41,253 square degrees of the sphere.

@MissUnderstands perhaps the super advanced civilization can make the pulsar tumble in such a way that it sweeps every part of the sky?

I reject the premise of your post: perhaps we don't know how THAT civilization did what they did, and we may be nowhere close to being able to do it ourselves, but in the immortal words: "I can imagine a lot."  Move some black holes into orbit around the pulsar to deflect the beams.  Or another large body, perhaps a massive circular grating, spinning to counteract its own gravity.  Move a system of masses (probably black holes again) into orbit around the pulsar such that tidal forces cause it to precess in a calculated way.  Just because you don't know how to do it doesn't mean no-one can.

@Erhannis that would work! The info bandwidth is just one bit, whether we exist or not. But that's all it would have to do. Wonder how you could encode any information to make it not natural, though. It's not quite definite enough to prove that aliens exist. That could happen by the neutron star bumping into another neutron star and transferring angular momentum. That's why the planet Uranus is tilted 97 deg on its side. We have seasons because another Mars smashed into Earth. Most of it formed the moon and that's why we have the seasons

@AlexP the beam on a pulsar doesn't need to be particularly loose either given the shape of the galaxy.  The cone only needs to expand out to about a thousand lightyears within a reasonable distance as long as it's sweeping the ecliptic.

@Erhannis I think “move some black holes” merely changes the nature of the unanswered questions without decreasing the number of unanswered questions. :-)

@SRM I mean, "move some black holes" has some pretty straightforward answers; you just e.g. use rockets to slingshot larger masses past it to move it in the direction you want.  Incredibly resource intensive, yes, but not fundamentally complex.  Now, what PATTERN you want the black holes to move in, I don't know.

Feed uranium to the Sun
Or rather any chemical element that's above neon and below iron, however uranium might do because it can spontaneously fission on its own. A star that has extra emission lines on top of what a main sequence stars normally emit, which are not explainable as a natural progression of a star's evolution, would certainly attract astronomers who have access to spectral astronomy (about our civilization's current level).
I'm not sure how much you'll need to feed to make those spectral lines discernible in the sun's normal light, but the least amount is in the ballpark of a whole planet. Also stellar turbulence is something that's not predictable to the degree of "it will emit for millions of years", yet several thousand years should be reachable with such approach. And since the star is the only thing that shines over enough light years, it's best to use exactly it to produce the required effect.

The problem with this would be that it could be explained as 'very large rock full of X flew/fell into star.'. And this is by no means an impossible occurrence.

@vinzzz001 you can adjust the contents of dump to a degree, and while "a very large rock hitting the star" is a plausible explanation, it would still cause extra attention to that star. After all, we do not require that our message will be correctly interpreted, just that it will be heard, and for this, here we did enough.

To make this method last somewhat longer, a large amount of asteroids could be set in decaying orbits, to 'periodically' fall in the star. This would reach a limit relatively quickly, as the star would get too heavy unless it emits most of the mass. The upside is that the content of the asteroids can be varied to increase unlikeliness it happens by happenstance. This would require measurements over VERY LONG periods of time to create results, though.

@vinzzz001 nice idea, after all it's still way below other answers in terms of spent energy.  But, you are probably being mislead about limits; a full Jupiter's worth of uranium dumped into the Sun would cause its mass to raise by about 0.1%, and if you'd situate a whole and large asteroid ring around the star that's full of uranium, so that they'll fall inside over several million years, the worst thing that would happen is that enough uranium would fission or beta-decay into plutonium - not a big deal for a beacon.

Lots and lots of robots - either as messengers carrying the signal itself, or as repeater stations.
I don't know how an assumption of godlike powers can go together with an assessment of real-life plausibility, so I have assumed merely ultra-civilizational powers, like stripping whole planets for raw materials and using whole stars for power plants.
Constraints:

Any machine that needs to run hot for a million years has to be a self-ordering system for which "run in the desired manner" is a deep local entropy maximum.

To send a signal across 20,000 light years requires either precision targeting of extremely coherent energy or an extremely bright source. We cannot build a bright enough source and make it last for long enough, so we must use precision targeting.

Unmanned per OP.


Solution: Robots which manufacture other robot manufacturers and robotic space probes, pulling power from a Dyson swarm and constructed out of materials ripped from one of the planets that wasn't ripped apart to build the Dyson swarm. In reverse constraint order:

Robots are not manned.

Matter in trajectory is the most coherent energy there is. Sure it's a lot slower, but we'll get there eventually, and the mass-energy savings will be astronomical. We can launch only towards stars which might have planets, have the autonomous probes course-correct en-route if they learn better.



Some of what we launch should be robot planet strippers and dyson
swarm builders. If we are using a light signal (lasers beamed from
from the home star dyson swarm to the target star system), these would
set up repeater stations in star systems unlikely to ever support
life.
If we are using a courier delivery system, these would be probe
builders launching courier probes. In either case, they will also
launch more robot planet strippers and dyson swarm builders to build
more repeater stations / courier builder stations.


Self-replication is the essence of the self-ordering system. Because we are not using living things but manufactured self-replicating tools, we can intelligently design their space of possible mutations and the mechanisms they use to ensure copy fidelity in order to keep them on mission eons in advance.


To keep the probes faithfully doing robot things instead of turning
into inert chunks of interstellar debris, we can either keep the
mission time short by building lots of builder stations, or we can
make the probes big and well-fueled enough to sustain a self-ordering
system onboard at as low a temperature as we can manage. (Picture a
generation ship or an organism, but populated by extremely lethargic
robots instead of humans or cells, and heated to a nice cozy 80
Kelvin.)

Repeater station scenario: over the few decades since advanced telescope design made it possible to detect it, astronomers had been mildly interested in a particular star which had grown dimmer and more infrared year by year, but still showed a spectrum for a main sequence star. Hypotheses of natural causes abound. By 2006 the main sequence star had disappeared entirely, leaving only a dim infrared speck. In 2025 the dim infrared speck suddenly turns naked eye visible as a ruby red speck in the sky, and astronomers pick up what can only be an intelligently designed signal riding on the beam of a laser.
Probe scenario: in 2025, without any warning, the Sun-Jupiter L2 point starts broadcasting radio waves.

200,000 spinning Dyson spheres with holes.
Your civilisation could build a giant shell around a star, to reflect light back inwards onto the star. They could design the shell to be capable of spinning at incredibile speeds. Then they could cut a giant hole into the sphere, so that the star is visible for perhaps a sixth of the time, for any observer within 60 degrees of the equator of the Dyson sphere.
Then they could build a huge number of these, oriented in different planes, and designed with their rotation speeds synchronised. Over time, inevitable engineering differences would let the spheres get out of phase, but the periods would stay similar for a much longer time. These would need to spin fast enough for their periods to be observed by watching civilisations, which would pose big engineering problems, but they would be easier to notice if there were more of them.

Instead of blocking out the entire sun, it may be sufficient to have billions of variable-transparency sunshield satellites situated so they block out the sun (in an artificial, recognizable on-off pattern) from the point of view of each star within the required radius

You could also make the transmitting pattern completely random, so that it would be very hard to explain with any configuration of planets.
Journal Article

This is a giant disco ball isn't it?

Must be omnidirectional.
Must be noticeable from the next spiral arm (20K ly).
Must actively attract attention.
Must broadcast uncrewed for a million years.

The biggest issue I see hear is the millions of years.
TV signals, think Contact (w/Jody Foster),  have been transmitted into space for decades and are slowly spreading out into the reaches of space.
If you want 20k ly then you just have to wait 20k years, which compared to the millions you require are nothing.  Use prime numbers, exponential numbers, or other simple not random patterns and it should get noticed.
Any coverage issues you have can be solved by adding antennas pointing in different directions.
The biggest issue is the millions of years.
I don't know if it could be permanently solved, but you would need a bunch of redundant autonomous repair robots.
Obviously, robot to repair the robots and machines.  More robots to collect and process resources.  You would probably require a 100 redundancies for each phase of the production line.
Whether it's enough to last a million years we can't be certain, but its probably your best shot.

What about signal attenuation over distance? The TV signals you mention that we've been broadcasting omnidirectionally attenuate to a level weaker than the CMB within a couple light years because of the inverse-square law, so they aren't even theoretically detectable even just from Alpha Centauri. For an omnidirectional radio signal to be detectable from 20k light years away, it would have to be such a powerful radio broadcast that I'd think there's a good chance it's literally a lethal amount of energy within at least a few light-years of its source, and would probably fry any such robots.

The OP say they have god like powers, so generating a shield should be a non-issue.  So shield the planet and make the antennas orbital and outside said shield.  Since god like power exist many options are possible maybe even just cancelling attenuation.  I don't want attenuation to exist, "snap my god finger" and boom no attenuation.  Obviously send out fleets of automated robots to evenly distribute and maintain antennas across the galaxies would be the boring answer.

@Idran it would only need to be as bright as a star.  And a smaller star than our sun at that, so no, not particularly lethal as long as you're at least 1AU away.

@cybernard OP added an edit yesterday to say "NEAR God like powers. No Violating physics" — so you can't just snap your fingers to make attenuation disappear. (But shielding is perfectly valid.)

Also they could put up the equivalent of window blinds in space, around a sun/star,  so they can open and close a shutter to make it blink at a pattern of there choosing.  Maybe glass or similar that can go from transparent to blocking on command like turning a light on and off with a desired pattern.  Now covering a whole star would take a lot of time and resources, but doable given the whole god-like thing.

Another choice, A multitude of worm hole generators opening wormholes at regular intervals allowing the single to travel further bypassing attenuation.

@cybernard You wouldn't even need to shutter the whole star. We can already detect some planets by seeing how they slightly dim their stars as they pass between us. If you could set a few such planets up such that their years formed a Fibonacci sequence (2nd one is 2x the length of inner, 3rd had 3x, 4th had 5x, 5th had 8x), that would surely get someone's attention. I'm not sure how long such orbits would be stable before they started interfering with each other. If you did that in three close systems, someone would definitely take a look.

@Perkins Oh, duh, that's a good point; thanks for the correction there

I think the major problem is that we have absolutely nothing active to guarantee a survival even for a millenia. My best bet is some passive thing, driven by the heat of decaying nuclear isotopes. That would create a current by thermoelectric way. Then an entirely passive antenna system would radiate it away. The required isotope has to be solid, cheap, heat resistant, easy to produce and a half life of about some hundreds of thousand years.
If you want something surely exist after a million years, then carve it in stone and shot the stone into the interstellar space. That will exist, but that will nothing radiate.
In general, we have nothing which would proven exist even after a millenia. That is because we have nothing technology which had existed a millenia before.
What we can do: we have various technological solutions, and some of them looking really, really stable. On of these are:
As energy source: decaying nuclear isotopes
Of course nothing radiation should ever get out, because they degrade material and it must exist even after a million of years. Best shieldable nuclear reaction are the alpha decay. Thus, we need an alpha decaying isotope, which is solid, has a high melting point, it is relative easy to produce, and it has a half life between a hundred thousand and a million years. We can easily produce a radioactive isotope if you can put something into a nuclear reactor and get it out. Thus, it should be created from a stable, also solid and not very costly nucleus, by swallowing a single neutron.
...quite surprisingly, after a little digging, I have found such a nucleus: ${}^{232}\mathrm{U}$! While it is an uranium isotope, it is completely unusable for any chain reaction or any energy production. It is a waste product. It is nothing more unusable like a ball of lead - except that you still need to keep a tremendous amount of regulations, to deal with it.
However, it decays by purely alpha decay with about 150000 years of half life.
So, put an ${}^{232}\mathrm{U}$ ball into some cm thin lead layer, and you have a heat source, not making any radioactivity, but heating a million year long (although after a millions of years, its activity will decay to about 1/100). That lead will also shade all possible secondary radiations (most importantly, gammas or beta decays from various contaminants).
...not exactly, my next U-232 decays in only about 70 years. U-233 decays in 150ky, but it is fissile. My next best bet is ${}^154\mathrm{Dy}$, also Dysprosium-154. It is not so easy to produce - probably you need large particle accelerators for that.
Result will be a warm lead ball. Nothing radioactive. It will be too primitive and too passive to go anything wrong with it.
As thermoelectric converter: anything stable
This wikipedia page suggest some silicon-germanium alloy. Yes, that is stable. Put this ball into a silicon-germanium layer. You will get a warm ball, giving you also a continuous stream of direct current.
As electromagnetic converter: possibly most passive electronics
You will need to lead this direct current into some electronics. First you need to convert it into alternating current, then into an antenna network.
Be primitive. Best if you do simple copper cables, so use simple copper cables. Nothing electronics, only a huge mess of copper cable.
On some places, you will likely need a lot of non-linear elements. Be again primitive, use big diodes, transistors, all of them must be big (forget "micro"electronics, it has to be pretty macro!). Roughly as electronics looked in the late 50s. For example, a diode must be a cm wide silicon or germanium cylinder.
Whole electronic had only a single purpose: to radiate a frequency modulated, analogous radio signal in infinite loop. Depending on the length of the data, probably you will need quite a large wide and diode/transistor network.
The electroengineers capable to design such a device, are yet living, but not long. Today, most guys with similar mental skills, are saying in their whole work day bullshits like this every day: "we are implementing the declarative cloud native pipelines on the second party knowledge channels".
That is because there are stupid bosses and companies paying them more for this crap, as if they would be designing an interstellar space beacon. Probably their knowledge will be soon lost. I think you have at most some decades back.
Finally...
If you are ready with the wire network, then pour the whole thing into an electromagnetically non-insulating, chemically very stable material, to keep it together, so strongly as possible, until the eternity. I think beton is probably a good candidate.
Then you can put the Ball into a space probe and send it after the Voyagers.
No one will remember you, or me, that we have ever existed, and this thing will be yet on the very beginning of its good, long voyage.

Unfortunately it seems Uranium-232 has a half life of 70 odd years, and the daughter isotopes in the decay chain emit radiation other than alpha particles - (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-232) - for instance Tl-208 in the decay chain emits gamma rays.
Uranium-233 however does have a half life of 160,000 years, but is fissile, and thus a mass of that over 15kg may well go boom unless very carefully shaped. It will also have daughter isotopes that emit things other than alpha particles.

@MNB Right. I mislooked the row. My next best bet would be Dysprosium-154. It is probably not so easy to produce, but it has very clean alpha-only decay chain, and about 150ky half life.

Universal LifeForm
you create a universal life form, something that can dwell in the Kuiper, eating Ice and Radiation - shitting copies of itself and hide the message - in the junk DNA that is always copied.
or
You build a lighthouse in space.
A sattelite-trio, one observing space, one listening to space, the other sending out a message into space- via laser. The observatory finds a planet in a solar system far away, calculates that its in the habitable zone (doable nowadays for super-earths). It then pre-calculates were the planet will be, given time and speed and the state of the universe in general.
The lighthouse sattelite then fires a  pulsed laser at the target. It crosses the distancedesert that is space and clashes into a little blue dot, lighting the sky at night for a minute or two. Just a disk of light, slipping over the clouds, racing at the speed of planetary rotation. Still enough energy to give you a sunburn, with the pulsed last greeting of a long dead civilization.
Finally the receiver, waits for a reply. It works not only as a "phone home" allowing to leave messages. But after it establishes connection, it also works like a internet switch on galactic level. Super slow, you can never hit those alderanians if you play games against them.

You specified 20,000 lightyears.  Our sun would be visible to the human eye for 50 lightyears, so that's not enough for just anyone to spot it...  But at 20,000 lightyears you'd still be getting about 380 nanowatts from it, which is definitely enough to pick up with the right kind of telescope.
So to generate that flash independently, you'd need to set off about 90 petatons worth of some kind of explosion.  Not really practical for us, but assuming god-like powers it could probably be done.
Alternatively, build a lamp-shade around the sun with shutters you can open and close.  I know you said omnidirectional, but most anyone you want to talk to is probably going to be on the ecliptic plane of the galaxy, so it's actually a fairly narrow swath you need to sweep, which gives you a lot of space for operating mechanism.
For how it could operate uncrewed for millions of years, that's actually pretty easy.  Just look at the direction our current technology is taking as our tools become capable of attending to more and more complex tasks without our direct intervention.  Eventually our entire supply chain could theoretically be run by robots, at which point self-repairing projects like this become quite possible.  It might break down if something causes it truly catastrophic damage, but that's true of anything.
Now the real problem is how do you send a signal that everyone else will recognize.  There are a number of ruminations out there on the "obvious" ways to do it, but they all assume that the aliens think like humans and have the same experiences we do.
As an example, say the first generation of life in the galaxy looks out into the night and sees nothing but unblinking points of light and the white noise of background radiation.
"Well that's easy," they say, "we'll just make something that pulses regularly and everyone will know we're here."
So they do.  And by the time we come along we look out there and see over 3400 pulsars and think, "Well, that's an interesting, natural phenomenon."  And whatever encoding has been developed over the last 9 billion years for putting data into those pulses is simply going over our heads and we're not noticing the Galactic Internet all around us.
Or what if the aliens are like dolphins?  It wasn't until the advent of modern, computer analysis for SONAR that we figured out why we couldn't crack their language.  It's because they can send each other whole pictures in a fair amount of detail.  Would a species like that ever go through the simplified pulse-code stage of communications that inspire all our ideas of Fibonacci sequences or digital encodings being "obvious"?  Or would their technology take an entirely different path and they're sending us pictures of their homeworld as we speak, and we're seeing it only as noise?  And keep in mind that we have a lot in common with dolphins...  Who even knows what a truly alien species might use for communication....
As for the Fermi paradox, there are two additional answers worth considering.
Firstly, it's quite possible that we're simply either wrong about how long life takes, or that the law of averages has thrown us a curve-ball, and we're the first ones to get this far.  That's how probability works.  Even if the odds of us being the first are a billion to one, it could still happen that way just because.
Secondly, as you've noticed, sending signals across galactic distances takes a heck of a lot of power.  Our early, hugely-inefficient radio transmissions just won't get very far.  A 1 megawatt transmission (and we've rarely used more than that for anything) spreads out to 1X10^-27 watts by the time it gets to just 1 lightyear away.  The signals from Voyager are about 1X10^-18 watts, and it takes an entire array of antennas pointed right at it to be able to hear it clearly.  And as time goes by we're doing less and less high-power broadcast.  It's just more efficient to use directional transmissions.  Plus our antennas and signal processing are better, so we just don't need to push as many watts.  Assuming any aliens have a similar technology progression to our own, we're probably not going to be able to hear much from them unless they're not only deliberately trying to make contact, but pointing their transmitter right at us.
Or if the waste emissions from some other technology they're using are on the same scale as small stars...  In which case we might well be best off just staying as quiet as we can and hoping for the best.

The sun only has an absolute magnitude of  4.83; so, it is only visible to the naked eye from ~50 light years, not 50,000.

@Nosajimiki I seem to have misread the number of zeros.  Well that's a bit more challenging...  Let me recalculate here...

Getting philosophical here
Alternatives using speed of light (=speed of causality; sub-c communication)
The question could be simplified to "is light appropriate to announce the presence of a sentient lifeform to other lifeforms?".
Since we assume godlike powers, we can assume the sender is able to create a sun, then let the sun vanish, then create a sun at the same spot again etc. to satisfy omni-directionality. The actual technique how to do it is not that important here and I take "uncrewed sending" as granted.
Important is: could such an approach indicate the presence to other lifeforms (us) in a reliable way?
It would suffice for announcing maybe, but the sender will never get a return message or has to wait million or more years for it in the worst case. Is it worthwhile to wait that long? Is the sending lifeform altruistic enough to establish a light beacon even if they may never be able to receive word from others?
Open is also if "active attention making" is  achieved. Using a sun could be considered a passive way of signaling by switching a light on and off. As would be everything else that is bound to the speed of light (or speed of causality). It is necessary for the receiver to actively observe the sky. All the infrastructure for observing is also necessary for the sender, but it can be considered to be ultra cheap compared to the sending beacon.
Conditions "visible from spiralarm (20k ly)" and "must send million+ years" contradict each other or can be fine tuned. Either 2*20k years to send and receive is enough to reach an already existing, sentient lifeform in the next spiralarm or it would be necessary to send several billions of years to cover the time a lifeform needs from primordial soup to high-tech sky observers. If we say this timespan is around 5 billion years (was 4,5 for us), a return message would take another 5 billion years. If we further assume the universe we know is the whole universe that exists and we assume the age estimation is close to correct with 13,8 bn years, this leaves a mere 3,8 bn years for the sending lifeform to develop the necessary godlike powers. Also they would have had to start evolving close to the big bang, which was a violent universe (probably) and forming of beings was not that easy.
In fact, this produces a contradiction, which shows that a sending lifeform does not need to send longer than the anticipated distance to the next receiving (and maybe answering/sending) lifeform. Therefore 20k (light)years seems to be too short and a million lightyears is already outside the milky way (100kly radius) - given the sender is sitting in the center (which is unlikely, because a violent place probably). But it's also not far enough to cover the next galaxy (Andromeda, 2.5Mly distance, 152,000ly across [Wikipedia]) - but it will reach it approx. 1.5 million years later.
Unadjustedly sending one million years anticipates this timespan to be enough to grant a lifeform to gain sky observing capabilities. While 100k years would be sufficient to cover the milkyway from center to rim already, if anticipating that a sky observing receiver already exists. In the same notion, sending only 100 years to an existing observer would probably be sufficient already - the signal would travel on its own for longer of course.
Then again this anticipates the highest probability to reach the next sentient lifeform to be within the same galaxy, which seems to be improbable.
It looks like that light (or anything else bound to speed of light/causality) is not suitable to announce and anticipate getting an answer. Which reduces the possibilities to an altruistic just sending lifeform to operate such a beacon.
Alternatives using distribution/expansion
If it is not feasible to announce and communicate, it is more sensible to spread out and reach other worlds and make direct contact - let's assume peacefully here, but the mileage may vary. But this also is bound to c for interstellar travels. Thus, the question could be rephrased to "Is faster-than-light-travel possible?" - Is FTL covered under "godlike" powers?
If not, and this seems to be most probably true, a sending lifeform has to resort to sub-c speeds. Also considering dying planets and suns within the timespan to send/receive the signal, it would be necessary to move on to new worlds in the meantime. If we assume the godlike powers allow them to form colonies, create new beacons and expand their area of influence - and also expand into the direction of the next sentient lifeform's world "by chance" - this would climax in a sun "somewhere close" to the receiver being used as a sending beacon. In this case making direct first contact between the lifeforms is imminent (cosmological timescale) anyway.
Alternatives using highest-level powers
The godlike powers are the key element in this one. A sending lifeform could come up with an idea to announce their presence in a way that the whole universe will be able to receive and observe in an instant:

Lifeform A: We create an anomaly in the expansion of space itself, letting it grow accelerated with no apparent reason - any sentient and evolved enough lifeform should get that this is so ridiculously impossible it must be something artificially created.
Lifeform B: You know what, we will introduce a cosmological signal we name "prime numbers". They are so odd, anyone will get that they were designed and not a coincidence.
Lifeform C: Why not have single proton atoms send a signal at 1420 MHz. Someone in that same room: Okay, but make it 420 MHz!
Lifeform D: Good luck guys, we shot a "Wow"-strong signal to a highly likely target but didn't receive any signal back yet. They probably are not even listening/observing.
...and so on.

In essence, what we take for granted/given/constant or are not yet able to explain at all could be attempts of being hailed since a long time ago. We were not able to understand the signal to this day, although it is something totally obvious to the sending lifeform.
We are convinced that it should be something so trivially obvious that we are able to detect it right now already. But this seems not to be the case - so it's open if we are ignorant to their signals, if really alone in the universe or if you assume there are lifeforms with godlike powers out there - and we are not yet able to understand and communicate back.
Hypothesis - mirror in the parrot cage
Since we know that signals like light can be influenced by gravitation, it could theoretically be possible that there is a blackhole or whatever that bends incoming light just so accurately that it is sent back to the receiver. The receiver then thinks "yay, a response!" and would even observe that the "others" acknowledge each signal by sending the same one back again. This situation will take a while to be resolved.
Conclusion

lightspeed takes too long for send/receive roundtrip
FTL is not possible
Altruistic trait to just send signals bound by speed of light and not wait for an answer would have had to result in several lifeforms starting to send already
Non-altruistic behavior is more likely
Therefore making (peaceful) direct contact by expansion/colonizing is feasible (in the long run)
We might not be ready and able to receive any (godlike) interstellar beacon signal yet, although they are in place already.


Re: "Hypothesis - mirror in the parrot cage"
You don't need anything exotic like a black hole to get your signal back. Light, for example, will come back to you quite easily if it hits anything at all reflective. So you're going to have to do "echo cancellation" already, or every moon, asteroid, or possibly even nearby dust speck will produce a false signal.

@sfink Idk if I can follow you. Having an interstellar sized mirror-reflective object would be equally exotic (idk, a planet made of silver?) and also the signal will get absorbed to some extent. A gravitational mirror potentially is able to repeat the full, undistorted incoming light signal back to the sender. What you are suggesting is "just" the normal light reflecting properties of any visible object. But those features are in place already if you check some light from a galaxy/star at 10Gly and are not substantially limited by light scattered at tiny dust specs along the way.

@Antares "The question could be simplified to "is light appropriate to announce the presence of a sentient lifeform to other lifeforms?". == I specifically didn't limit it to EM radiation.

@Antares "Since we assume godlike powers, we can assume the sender is able to create a sun, then let the sun vanish," == I'll change it to near God like powers. Otherwise you can make big galaxy sized smiley faces.

@MissUnderstands (1) You didn't limit it to EM radiation (which stands representative for speed of causality - so everything/anything "relativistic" we know of), but if you also don't expect FTL to exist then you are out of luck assuming getting a response in time. Or you need far larger timespans than just million years of sending (and waiting). The amount of altruism necessary to "just send and announce" becomes a decisive factor. (2) Hmm, this renders a good portion not applicable anymore. But I understand your point.

@Antares "t then you are out of luck" == yeah, that was my conclusion. It's also the explanation for why the Galaxy seems empty.

@Antares "assuming getting a response in time" == I'm not trying to establish communication, just announce To everyone else that they're not alone. My point is that no one else in the Galaxy has ever done this. So either it's impossible or there isn't anyone

@Antares " amount of altruism" == I have cancer of the altruism, and I'm just going to shut my eyes and b'lieve real hard that other civilizations will too.

The million years transmission time with only a 20kLY range isn't necessarily a contradiction. It simply assumes that there is some species within range that is also within 1 million years of the sender on the technological development track. Longer range would give better odds, of course, but it's not contradictory to not contact the entire galaxy if it's impractical to do so and you think there's good odds of somebody listening within a shorter range.

@Antares Yes, I'm talking about ordinary reflection off of any body that is not coated with black paint. Sure, it's not the full undistorted signal, but neither is the signal that bends around a massive gravitational body, due to dust, hydrogen, etc. It's the problem with shining headlights into fog. Unless you're encoding the information in something that isn't preserved by reflection? Anyway, I'm just saying you have to deal with the fog reflections already, with fog at varying distances, so a black hole isn't that different. We wouldn't be fooled.

@Perkins Sure, if the sender is convinced there is sufficient chance of others in the cosmic vicinity (aka "front yard"), this will do. It is just strange, because the signal will travel on anyway, so it sends a million years then shuts down - but why? IF energy is not a problem, they could continue. IF 20kly is enough they could rise chances if sending longer as well. Or they would chose only to send a 100 years or so under the assumption there is someone at 20kly lisenting already.

@MissUnderstands If we consider aliens also denying the usefulness of making contact as you do, then you of course cut the scenario dark from the start. But if they do not have altruistic traits it is probably better they stay where they are and never discover us.

@Antares  The signal travels on, but becomes very difficult to detect without exponentially more power.  So you have to consider both instantaneous power generation and how long the power source will last.  The million years would be primarily to account for differences in developmental level. If you have some reason to believe that there is life within 20kly, then the next question is how far behind you might they be and how long might it take them to figure out how to reply. The broadcast is insanely expensive, but a reply is something we could probably pull off with near-future tech.

@MissUnderstands "So either it's impossible or there isn't anyone" -- There is the third option I tried to convey: We cannot tell (yet).

@Antares We can't tell at the current time. But I believe we can infer that the third option is actually the first, that it's just impossible. As evidence, I present the fact that of all the trillions of stars we can see, none are attracting our attention. My point wasn't to ask whether we could do it, that was how someone rephrased my question. I'm still not sure what world building is, but it looks interesting. My actual question was, doesn't the fact that we can't see a beacon imply that it's almost certainly impossible? Either that, or we're truly alone in the universe.

Stop a star
We take a star and bring its rotation to a halt.
That's it. A star that doesn't rotate simply doesn't exist as far as we know. It would most certainly draw attention from our experts in the field.
Want to make it more obvious? Free the star from its galaxy. Just place it somewhere in intergalactic space, where it won't rejoin a nearby galaxy in its lifetime.
Want to make it even more obvious? Place a few of them in a relative 'small area' (far enough separated to not influence each-other). Maybe 4 on the corners of a regular tetrahedron? The shape should be reconstructible from almost any angle.

"Broadcast" in the traditional sense is probably overkill.  You just need something that very obviously stands out as unnatural and intentional.
The most straightforward option would be to modify a star.  They already broadcast great distances, plus they're the sort of thing your extra-terrestrials are likely already looking at.  You just need to make your star look very different than every other star.
Stars follow a fairly well-defined lifecycle that determines their color and brightness as they age.  A star outside of the main sequence would be very noticeable to astronomers.
Build a series of extremely large translucent filters in a variety of colors.  Place these into an orbit around your sun so that their orbit is in line with the galactic plane.  As they orbit, they'll have a kaleidoscope effect, altering the color of your star's light.  Distant astronomers will see your star as a normal yellow star, then a year later it's red, then later it's blue, wait now it's ... green?  The colors occur in a repeating pattern, but the sequence doesn't match anything known in nature and the colors change far too quickly to be natural processes.
The good part about something like this is that it's a completely passive system.  The sun does all the work, you shouldn't have anything to maintain.  As long as your filters are in a stable orbit and can survive (or avoid) the occasional comet, a million years shouldn't be too unreasonable.

I can't award two best answers,can I?

A 'Stellar Kaleidoscope"? Maybe a "Celestial Kaleidoscope"? That said, I imagine the lenses being round, to prevent deformation under their own weight, kinda like planet sized marbles.

A simple-ish alternative is to build planetary systems with particular characteristics. That is, planetary systems that would not be expected to form naturally.  These could be: a) chains of resonances that encode integer sequences of mathematical importance (such as consecutive primes or Fibonacci sequence), or b) exotic systems that are really unusual, like rings of co-orbital planets.
I explored this idea in this blog post a few years ago: https://planetplanet.net/2021/10/25/cosmic-time-capsule/
This ended up serving as motivation and we wrote three scientific papers about these ideas.  Here are the links if you're interested.  In the process, I figured out a new type of co-orbital system (which I call a horseshoe constellation).
Clement et al (2022):  Mathematical encoding within multiresonant planetary systems as SETI beacons
Raymond et al (2023):  Constellations of co-orbital planets: horseshoe dynamics, long-term stability, transit timing variations, and potential as SETI beacons
Raymond et al (2023):  Survival and dynamics of rings of co-orbital planets under perturbations

Take a massive supernova surrounded by lots of gas and make the super nova emit light and gas at an astronomical scale such that it makes waves (perhaps feed the supernova something every few months to cause such disruptions, such facility can be on a nearby planet/asteroid) and have spaces in between the waves just like a Morse code and in a few years it should have a self sustaining code observable from millions of lys away and since it's a supernova, it'll stay for a few millions of years. The waves should look like waves emitted by an object on water

Only downside is that also gravitational waves travel at the speed of light. So after a few years the signal has traveled only a few lightyears and needs millions of years to reach someone million of lightyears away.

The Rainbow Onion Ringworld
Similar to the 200,000 Dyson spheres with holes, except I didn't follow why it needed so many or why you would use full spheres.
R136a1 is 160k light years away, and we can see it, so I think a single star is enough as an omnidirectional "backlight". No smiley faces required.
Build a thick, spinning ring around the star. (Like if you filled in the orbit of a satellite body with material.) Either leave gaps in it, or have transparent portions. Space the gaps out to send your signal (as a primitive example, the pattern of gaps could encode a message in Morse code). Except you'll want more gap than substance, because you'll be overlapping a lot of these.
You don't want a sphere, because at the poles the sphere would either be "always off" or "always on". Always off means nobody in that direction will ever get a signal. Always on means you have a ring! (Well, I suppose you could have a sphere that is transparent everywhere but near the equator, but what's the point?)
Now build another ring with a slightly larger diameter, tilted at an angle compared to the first. The resulting signal at the "hinge" point is now a combination of the occlusions from both rings, but that's just a small matter of mathematics. Continue building rings until the whole of the star is covered. It's like an onion if each layer didn't cover the whole of the inner onion. You don't want the hinge points of all the shells to line up if you want to be able to signal those 2 directions, though it might improve the encoding if you do.
The wider the "band" of the rings, the fewer of them you need, but also the fewer bits you can have in your message. (1 ring, aka a sphere, has 0 bits at the poles and many bits at the equator.) Or equivalently, the closer the band extends to the poles, the slower it's traveling around at its top and bottom. So there's some kind of balance there. But it's not a hard limit, where you end up with so many ring shells that there's too little "on" time—I haven't done the math, and don't know how to, but if you get too much occlusion with one star, "just" use 2 or half a dozen. Each will only be good for part of the sky, but you can use fewer and thicker rings than with just 1 star. (Even only 2 would allow using a single hinge point for all shells, since each star's hinges would only completely eliminate the transmission in 2 cones.)
You'll want stationkeeping to keep everything properly lined up for a long time, where here I'm using stationkeeping to mean the speed and tilt of the ring. Fortunately you have an enormous source of energy to draw on in the center of your onion. You'll want to run autonomous repair robots and speed correction thrusters off of that energy. The bigger problem will be dissipating all of it! Your advanced civilization will basically be coating the inside of the rings with solar cells that try to absorb as much as possible to keep it from being reflected back to the "cool" side of the inner rings, and then using what energy they can for repair and stationkeeping, and re-emitting the rest to get it away (with limited frequency, polarization, spin, or whatever to keep from adding noise to the raw signal).
Stationkeeping will burn mass. The radiation from the star will also be transmuting your ring material. Maybe these can be combined to get rid of the weird brittle isotopes by ablating the inner surface and using it as propellant? You'd still build up a cloud of weird crap orbiting with and between the rings. Bleh, engineering details.
Sticking with the on/off mentality, you can make it a progressive transmission (using the terminology from progressive JPEG files): the open/closed inner part of each ring could have a gross scale where it's 90% open, but actually composed of a more detailed pattern that averages out to 90%. So at first, the observer would spot the star winking in a regular pattern, but then within those winks it's actually flickering on and off, and within those flickers are more flickers, etc.
Plus, the "open" parts might mask off frequency bands to encode more bits (eg, instead of being clear, it's yellow). (This is where the rainbow part of the rainbow onion comes from.)
Alternative: Blinking Shell
Or simplify the science at the cost of potentially impossible engineering: build a single Dyson sphere with its inside coated in solar panels and its outside with lights (or just be a giant filament). Convert all the light to electricity, modulate it electronically with your chosen pattern, and emit it back out on the outside. I suspect a star's worth of energy would make this impossible to sustain without vaporizing whatever your outside is made of, but to a first approximation it is very simple.
Alternative: Plain Ringworld
...and having written all that, I realize the simplest version of my first answer is actually very straightforward: use two stars, a single solid ring around each star, with the ring spinning around its poles. (The ring's poles could be aligned with the star's, or not.) It only gives you a regularly blinking on-off, on-off, but maybe that's good enough? You could at least weld two rings together around each star, so you get a fast off - fast on - fast off - long on pattern, to make it less likely that observers will just write it off as a natural phenomenon.
